# How to implement virtual scroll for 4 images in a row using React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently displaying the image in

```
 {images.map((image, index) =>    <img key={index} src={image} alt="info"></img>      )}
```

and here 5 images per row have to be displayed. Say I have a list of files in an array:

```
 MyArray = [1.png,2.png,3.png,4.png,5.png,................]
```

So currently I am displaying it as

```
1,2,3,4,5
 6,7,8,9,10
```

but I am unable to implement the virtual scroll in React after trying [react virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized).

I have 2 queries:

1. Do I have to choose list or grid based scrolling?
2. I have stored an array in **MyArray**, so how can I send the array to the below list?

   ```
   <List
     width={rowWidth}
     height={listHeight}
     rowHeight={rowHeight}
     rowRenderer={this.renderRow}
     rowCount={this.list.length}
     overscanRowCount={3} 
   />
   ```

[image: after implementing grid using react virtualized] i am displaying svg's

updated implementions:

Comment: A code sandbox or codepen would be helpful. Please post your code.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-lederberg-pylkh?fontsize=14  @Ashish as code sandbox not accepting svgs and installing packages also but i am implemented logic there

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `Grid` srolling.
Please see basic implementation for 4 images in a row below. You will need to adjust styling and other visual elements as per your needs.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Grid } from 'react-virtualized';

// Grid data as an array of arrays
const myArray = [
  [1.png,2.png,3.png,4.png],
  [5.png,6.png,7.png,8.png],
  // And so on...
];

function cellRenderer ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
  return (
    <img
      key={key}
      style={style}
      src={myArray[rowIndex][columnIndex]}
      alt="info"
    />
  )
}

// Render your grid
ReactDOM.render(
  <Grid
    cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
    columnCount={4}
    columnWidth={100}
    height={300}
    rowCount={myArray.length}
    rowHeight={30}
    width={300}
  />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Also, here is the code that I ran on my machine to test the implementation. I made it with `create-react-app`. Screenshot of running app included.

[image: testing_screenshot]

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from 'react-virtualized';

// Grid data as an array of arrays
const myArray = [
  ['https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg'],
  ['https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg'],
  ['https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg'],
  ['https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg'],
  ['https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg'],
  ['https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg'],
  ['https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg'],
  ['https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg'],
  ['https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg'],
  ['https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg'],
  ['https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg'],
  ['https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/NVHKPPq.jpg'],
  // And so on...
];

function cellRenderer ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
  return (
      <div
        key={key}
      >
      <img
        style={style}
        src={myArray[rowIndex][columnIndex]}
        alt="info"
      />
      </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>TESTING WITH CATS</h1>
          <Grid
            cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
            columnCount={4}
            columnWidth={100}
            height={200}
            rowCount={myArray.length}
            rowHeight={100}
            width={1200}
          />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Implementation with SVGs.
[image: testing_with_svg]

Dexter, please make sure all your images are inside of the public folder (screenshot below).

[image: folder_structure_screenshot]

You will need to manually add them to `myArray`. Alternatively - you can write a function that automatically imports them for you and pushes them into smaller arrays of 4.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from 'react-virtualized';

// Grid data as an array of arrays
const myArray = [
  ['/images/11.svg','/images/11.svg','/images/11.svg','/images/11.svg'],
  ['/images/11.svg','/images/11.svg','/images/11.svg','/images/11.svg'],
  ['/images/11.svg','/images/11.svg','/images/11.svg','/images/11.svg'],
  ['/images/11.svg','/images/11.svg','/images/11.svg','/images/11.svg'],
  // And so on...
];

function cellRenderer ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
  return (
      <div
        key={key}
      >
          <img
            style={style}
            src={myArray[rowIndex][columnIndex]}
            alt="info"
          />
      </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>TESTING WITH SVGS</h1>
          <Grid
            cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
            columnCount={4}
            columnWidth={100}
            height={200}
            rowCount={myArray.length}
            rowHeight={100}
            width={1200}
          />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: not working for svgs@Artem please check updated question

Comment: please check this sandbox i implemented svg like this https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-lederberg-pylkh?fontsize=14

Comment: Hey Dexter, the sandbox is not working for me (404 - not found). Could you update it, please? Also, could you please give me 1 or 2 svgs that you are trying to use?

Comment: @Artem you download any svg file it is fine and code sandbox not accepting svg that's the issue

Comment: @Artem here please chek this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-euujzn here i we have images the logic whic i ma using displayinh svg as list

Comment: @Dexter. I added svg support in my answer. Good luck!

Comment: @ArtemK i updated but still empty please check updated question and what is the style ur implementing

Comment: You need to make sure your image path's are strings when they get placed in `src`. It looks like everything is working, but the `src` is broken